# Cpp program using producer and consumer (mutex locks) on a shared buffer

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have a c++ code where I am trying to produce some values into thread and consume it using 2 other consumer threads. Mutex locks are used to provide synhronisation. But output does not show a random progress for the threads, as in, producer produces 5 at a time, 1 of the consumer consumes it all at a time not giving the other consumer or the producer a chance before it completely consumes the queue. ANy help would be much appreciated. I am also attaching the code and sample output.

```
// CPP program to demonstrate the given task
`#include <iostream>`
`#include <pthread.h>`

#include <queue>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

#define MAX 10

using namespace std;

// Declaring global variables
int sum_B = 0, sum_C = 0;
int consumerCount1 = 0;
int consumerCount2 = 0;

// Shared queue
queue<int> Q;
int item=0;

// Function declaration of all required functions
void* producerFun(void*);
void* add_B(void*);
void* add_C(void*);

// Getting the mutex
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

pthread_cond_t dataNotProduced =
                    PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t dataNotConsumed =
                    PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

// Function to generate random numbers and
// push them into queue using thread A

void* producerFun(void*)
{
    static int producerCount = 0;

    // Initialising the seed
    srand(time(NULL));

    while (1) {
        // Getting the lock on queue using mutex
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        if (Q.size() < MAX && item < MAX)
        {

            // Getting the random number
            int num = rand() % 10 + 1;


            // Pushing the number into queue
            Q.push(num);

            producerCount++;
            item++;

            cout << "Produced: " << num << " item: "<<item<<endl;

            pthread_cond_broadcast(&dataNotProduced);
        }

        // If queue is full, release the lock and return
        else if (item == MAX) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            cout<<"\nLeaving";
            //sleep(1);
            continue;
        }

        // If some other thread is exectuing, wait
        /*else {
            cout << ">> Producer is in wait.." << endl;
            pthread_cond_wait(&dataNotConsumed, &mutex);
        }*/

        // Get the mutex unlocked
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        //sleep(0.5);
    }
}

// Function definition for consumer thread B
void* add_B(void*)
{

    while (1) {

        // Getting the lock on queue using mutex
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        // Pop only when queue has at least 1 element
        if (Q.size() > 0) {
            // Get the data from the front of queue
            int data = Q.front();


            // Add the data to the integer variable
            // associated with thread B
            sum_B += data;
            consumerCount1++;

            // Pop the consumed data from queue
            Q.pop();

            item--;
            cout << "B thread consumed: " << data << "cc1: "<<consumerCount1<<endl;


            //pthread_cond_signal(&dataNotConsumed);
        }

        // Check if consmed numbers from both threads
        // has reached to MAX value
        /*else if (consumerCount2 + consumerCount1 == MAX) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            return NULL;
        }*/

        // If some other thread is exectuing, wait
        else {
            cout << "B is in wait.." << endl;
            pthread_cond_wait(&dataNotProduced, &mutex);
        }

        // Get the mutex unlocked
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        //sleep(0.5);
    }
}

// Function definition for consumer thread C
void* add_C(void*)
{

    while (1) {

        // Getting the lock on queue using mutex
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        // Pop only when queue has at least 1 element
        if (Q.size() > 0) {

            // Get the data from the front of queue
            int data = Q.front();

            // Add the data to the integer variable
            // associated with thread B
            sum_C += data;

            // Pop the consumed data from queue
            Q.pop();
            item--;
            consumerCount2++;

            cout << "C thread consumed: " << data << "cc2: "<<consumerCount2<<endl;

            //pthread_cond_signal(&dataNotConsumed);
        }

        // Check if consmed numbers from both threads
        // has reached to MAX value
        /*else if (consumerCount2 + consumerCount1 == MAX)
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            return NULL;
        }*/

        // If some other thread is exectuing, wait
        else {
            cout << ">> C is in wait.." << endl;
            // Wait on a condition
            pthread_cond_wait(&dataNotProduced, &mutex);
        }

        // Get the mutex unlocked
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        //sleep(0.5);
    }
}

// Driver code
int main()
{
    // Declaring integers used to
    // identify the thread in the system
    pthread_t producerThread, consumerThread1, consumerThread2;

    // Function to create a threads
    // (pthread_create() takes 4 arguments)
    int retProducer = pthread_create(&producerThread,
                    NULL, producerFun, NULL);
    int retConsumer1 = pthread_create(&consumerThread1,
                    NULL, *add_B, NULL);
    int retConsumer2 = pthread_create(&consumerThread2,
                    NULL, *add_C, NULL);

    // pthread_join suspends execution of the calling
    // thread until the target thread terminates
    //if (!retProducer)
        pthread_join(producerThread, NULL);
    //if (!retConsumer1)
        pthread_join(consumerThread1, NULL);
    //if (!retConsumer2)
        pthread_join(consumerThread2, NULL);

    // Checking for the final value of thread
    if (sum_C > sum_B)
        cout << "Winner is Thread C" << endl;
    else if (sum_C < sum_B)
        cout << "Winner is Thread B" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Both has same score" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBmAW.jpg)

Comment: Please post text as text, not as image. Please provide a [mcve]. Your code is not minimal. Is there a reason you are using `pthread` instead of `std::thread`? `stdlib.h` is a C header, not a C++ header. You should use `cstdlib`.

Comment: I can't compile your code: https://wandbox.org/permlink/VagiaqIl7kC535rf That's a good example why you should avoid `using namespace std;`

Comment: Why do you expect _"a random progress"_? `pthread_mutex_lock` probably uses some kind of sleep for the waiting thread. That means the running thread can unlock the mutex and lock it again while the other thread is waiting. It doesn't recognize that the lock was unlocked.

Comment: Alright thats exactly I was looking for..why does it lock again. How can I prevent it from locking again and give a fair access to other waiting threads as well?

Comment: Add a sleep for the current thread. You should use `std::thread`. There you have `std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms)`. Your sleep call `sleep(0.5)` doesn't work because `sleep` expects an integer and `0.5` is implicitly converted to `0`. But I'm sure you have enabled the compiler warnings and already know it.